# How to create Data control and View Object from Java classes in ADF

Tags: java, xml-parsing, oracle-adf

**I have an XML file**

```
<employees>
  <employee id="111">
    <firstName>Rakesh</firstName>
    <lastName>Mishra</lastName>
    <location>Bangalore</location>
  </employee>
  <employee id="112">
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Davis</lastName>
    <location>Chennai</location>
  </employee>
  <employee id="113">
    <firstName>Rajesh</firstName>
    <lastName>Sharma</lastName>
    <location>Pune</location>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

**I am unmarshaling it into Employee  class using**

```
public class DOMParserDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Get the DOM Builder Factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    //Get the DOM Builder
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    //Load and Parse the XML document
    //document contains the complete XML as a Tree.
    Document document = 
      builder.parse(
        ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("xml/employee.xml"));

    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Iterating through the nodes and extracting the data.
    NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

      //We have encountered an <employee> tag.
      Node node = nodeList.item(i);
      if (node instanceof Element) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.id = node.getAttributes().
            getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();

        NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
          Node cNode = childNodes.item(j);

          //Identifying the child tag of employee encountered. 
          if (cNode instanceof Element) {
            String content = cNode.getLastChild().
                getTextContent().trim();
            switch (cNode.getNodeName()) {
              case "firstName":
                emp.firstName = content;
                break;
              case "lastName":
                emp.lastName = content;
                break;
              case "location":
                emp.location = content;
                break;
            }
          }
        }
        empList.add(emp);
      }

    }

    //Printing the Employee list populated.
    for (Employee emp : empList) {
      System.out.println(emp);
    }

  }
}
```

I want to create a UI in ADF which will have the fields populated with the output data.

Can somebody please guide me how can I achieve it?

Comment: good example here http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to these tutorials that shows how to create Data Controls from Java classes: [Using Bean Data Controls](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_36/jdtut_11r2_36.html) and [Java Class Data Controls and ADF Binding](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/java_class_data_control_and_ad)